# DNS Server not responding

Tags: dns

[image]
i have dns server i have configure it from [Ubuntu bind9 help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto)

i have A record of ubuntu-server.local

i am unable to ping it from  ubuntu machine

i am able to ping it from windows 7 machine ...& working 100%

dig

[image]

[image]

Comment: & web Browsing working fine on all machine

Comment: my avg pinging to google from windows machine is 238 ms  & from ubuntu machine is 240 ms

Comment: before dns server both pining to google.com at avg 527 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the machine is unable to resolve "ubuntu-server.local", it doesn't even get as far as actually pinging it.

Which DNS server is responsible for the .local domain on your LAN? You need to add the IP for it into the list of resolvers in Network Manager so the machine can find it, since it's not something that would be returned by any DNS server on the general Internet.

Comment: i think u haven't noticed the comments i have added above in comments .... see the avg pining result ...... its just from my ip (ubuntu machine ) i cannot ping ubuntu-server.local (local dns server ) i can ping it from server ,  can ping it from windows 7 machine but i cant ping it from ubuntu desktop 11.10 machine .... my internet working properly , web Browsing working properly as shown in above comments ...

Comment: @MuhammadQasim: Re-read this answer. Your comments are unrelated to this answer. I'm pretty sure Caesium is spot on. You need to make sure that your machine is using your DNS server and not some other server. A good way to test this is to run `dig ubuntu-server.local` and see which IP address is being used for the server.

Comment: Okay, and "cat /etc/resolv.conf" has 192.168.0.50 as one of the nameserver entries? You omitted the command you ran to get the dig output which may have been useful to see if you had to specify a DNS server to query. It may have to be the top entry in resolv.conf, I can't remember offhand if another server returning "doesn't exist" will cause it to stop trying any subsequent ones..

Comment: updated ....... cat /etc/resolv.conf